# Got a "initializer element is not a compile-time" error when using Clang 3.0 to compile coreutils library

Tags: c, compilation, clang

The following C code is part of lib in GNU coreutils (Click [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/localeconv.c;h=8f2d08402fb989ab0c74a630a45a3a255e05fc49;hb=HEAD)).

I got a compilation error using Clang (version 3.0) as follows:

> localecove.c:73:5: error: initializer element is not a compile-time
>   constant

(Note that, Line 73 is indicated using a comment)

I am confused, what's the matter!? Or is it something wrong with the compiler?

```
#include <limits.h>

struct lconv *
localeconv (void)
{
    static /*const*/ struct lconv result = 
    {/*Line 73*/ 
        /* decimal_point */ ".",
        /* thousands_sep */ "",
        /* grouping */ "",
        /* mon_decimal_point */ "",
        /* mon_thousands_sep */ "",
        /* mon_grouping */ "",
        /* positive_sign */ "",
        /* negative_sign */ "",
        /* currency_symbol */ "",
        /* frac_digits */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* p_cs_precedes */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* p_sign_posn */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* p_sep_by_space */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* n_cs_precedes */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* n_sign_posn */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* n_sep_by_space */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* int_curr_symbol */ "",
        /* int_frac_digits */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* int_p_cs_precedes */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* int_p_sign_posn */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* int_p_sep_by_space */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* int_n_cs_precedes */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* int_n_sign_posn */ CHAR_MAX,
        /* int_n_sep_by_space */ CHAR_MAX
    };

    return &result;
}
```

Comment: Run the preprocessor with the `-E` option and inspect the output. Most probably `CHAR_MAX` expands to a non-constant expression.

Comment: Type of member of `lconv` is seems to be different. [demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zc3nyZazUzHP0XaQ) I think the error message  get out if this type of conversion occurs.

Comment: The code assumes the members are in a specific order, but apparently they aren't and according to the ISO C standard don't have to be. You can use designated initializers to fix this or try getting this fixed upstream.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, you're right. I found a warning before this error:   localeconv.c:83:25: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *'
      with an expression of type 'int';
      /* frac_digits */ CHAR_MAX,